# DJANGO:How to remove empty QuerySet from the list of QuerySet

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

*This is my list of QuerySets.Now my concern is to remove the list of empty QuerySet i.e.QuerySet [] from the given list.*

**[QuerySet [], QuerySet [], QuerySet [], QuerySet [],[User: kharel321, User: kharelkharel]>]**

*Expected OutPut*

**[[User: kharel321, User: kharelkharel]]**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
your_queryset_list = [QuerySet [], QuerySet [], QuerySet [], QuerySet [],[User: kharel321, User: kharelkharel]>]
result = [queryset for queryset in your_queryset_list if queryset]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

```
if  not user.exists():
   ...some action
```